# How do we construct a linear functional that maps a sequence in a normed space to a sequence in the complex numbers?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose we have a sequence $(x_n)$ in a normed space (underlying field is C) and a sequence $(c_n)$ in the complex numbers. How do we construct a linear functional that maps $(x_n)$ to $(c_n)$ for each n? The most obvious way to define a linear functional is consider just the span of $x_1$ and map $ax_1$ to $ac_1$, and we easily extend this to any finite n and just consider the linear combinations. But I am stuck on how to do the extension for the entire sequence because it is infinite. Of course, it is possible to stop at some N, and just use the Hahn-Banach theorem to extend to the entire space, but if we do that, we can not say for certain that $x_{N+1}$ is mapped to $c_{N+1}$

Comment: It is not always possible. Taking $x_n=ne_1$ any linear functional must satisfy $T(x_n)=n T(e_1)$, so $(c_n)_n$ cannot be, for ecample, $c_n=e^n$. I think you need some extra assumption such as being a "basis" or being linearly independent.